# Index out of range error when trying to download image using kingfisher to use in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, kingfisher

I have created a collection view controller that acts as the navigation system of my app and the collection view is created in `TabBar.swift` and I've got 2 more view controllers that inherit from the class `TabBar`. So `TabBar` is basically a base view controller.

```
struct OpenViewController {
    var viewController: UIViewController
    var cellImage: UIImage
}

class TabBar: UIViewController {
    var viewControllerList = [OpenViewController]()
}

extension TabBar: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    // Selecting a cell and navigating to another view controller
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // To present the view controllers
        let openViewController = self.viewControllerList[indexPath.row]
        self.present(openViewController.viewController, animated: false)
    }
}
```

The above code snippet takes the user to a specified view controller when the user taps on a cell in the collection view. And the below code snippet shows how I've specified the view controllers in the other view controllers:

```
class SecondScreen: TabBar {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://SomeURL")

        let downloader = ImageDownloader.default
        downloader.downloadImage(with: url!) { result in

            switch result {

            case .success(let value):
                print(value.image)

                self.viewControllerList = [
                    OpenViewController(viewController: FirstScreen(), cellImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "error")),
                    OpenViewController(viewController: ThirdScreen(), cellImage: value.image)
                ]

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get Index out of range error and the app crashes.

Comment: Add a comment where you get an error ! It will be helpfull

Comment: Nothing can get out of bounds here. probably it's somewhere else in your code

Comment: Did you add data source methods ?

Comment: @Cœur okay thanks. i will take care next time.

Comment: @TalCohen, Nope I know that this is where the error is happening cuz the code under didSelectItemAt cannot find the viewControllerList

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh the error is that the code under didSelectItemAt cannot find viewControllerList cuz its inside switch case but once its outside that, it works properly. So why can't I place it outside you may ask and that's bcuz then I can't put the downloaded image to the view controller list

Comment: If there is a way to place viewControllerList outside the switch case and still include the image then it will work, hope someone can help me with that

Comment: Have you added an exception breakpoint? It should catch where you're going out of bounds so you'll at least know the line.